# jsTree - don't select disabled child nodes with parent?

Tags: jquery, jstree

Using the jsTree plugin, the developer argues that disabled child nodes should be selected when the parent node is selected - I disagree. To overcome this, I figure that I can just deselect disabled child nodes programmatically. I have done so with the following:

```
  $("#selectionTree").on("select_node.jstree",
    function(evt, data) {
      var currentNode = data.node;
      var children = $("#selectionTree").jstree("get_children_dom", currentNode);
      for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON($(children[i]).attr('data-jstree'));
        if (obj['disabled'] == true) {
          $(children[i]).jstree("deselect_node", children[i]);
        }
      }
    }
```

I have two problems though.

1. <del>I can't make this work in the fiddle but it works in my environment</del>
2. Disabled nodes are selected when the parent is selected if the parent node is collapsed i.e. my code only works when the disabled child nodes are visible to the user.

I'm thinking the solution is the jQuery rather than the jsTree so any ideas?

EDIT: My code example now works in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf55r7qt/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution tested on a 1-deep tree works. I just added this function:

```
//select parents children except disabled ones
//test on 1-deep
$("#selectionTree").on("select_node.jstree", function(evt, data) {
    var currentNode = data.node;

    //rember opened state for later
    var openedState = currentNode['state']['opened'];

    //need to open node for accruate selection       
    $('#selectionTree').jstree('open_node', currentNode);

        //get child nodes
    var children = $(this).jstree("get_children_dom", currentNode);

        //this allows selections parent nodes to deselect children (without it, there is no three-state)
    if ($("#" + currentNode['a_attr']['id'] + " > i").hasClass("jstree-undetermined")) {
      for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        $(children[i]).jstree("deselect_node", children[i]);
      }
    }

        //loop through child nodes and select all except disabled nodes
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      var obj = $.parseJSON($(children[i]).attr('data-jstree'));
      if (obj['disabled'] == true) {
        $(children[i]).jstree("deselect_node", children[i]);
      }
    }

        //return parent to closed state if was already
    if (openedState == false) {
      $(this).jstree('close_node', currentNode);
    }

});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf55r7qt/6/

Answer (score -1):

You can try this (works for me):

```
'checkbox': {
  'cascade_to_disabled': false,
}
```